# Arduino int problem

Tags: programming

I made a counter to count pulses:

```cpp
int count  = 0 ;
.
.
.
setup()
{    
}    

while (count <= 35000)
{    
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(500);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);

  count = count + 1;
}
```

But when I try `while(count <= 40000)`, it does not stop counting.

Answer (score 7):

`int` in AVR GCC is [16 bits](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Type_Layout). ***All*** possible `int` values are less than 32767.

Comment: To be precise, the maximum value of `int` on this platform is 32767. If you add 1 to 32767 you get -32768 which then counts back up to 0, then up to 32767 and so on.

Comment: If you made it `unsigned int` then the maximum value is 65535 which would work for counting up to 40000.

Answer (score 2):

You have reached the maximum number that an `int` can represent. That is **32767**.

`int` is a variable type that is made up of **16 bits**. It is **signed**, meaning that it can represent positive and negative numbers.

Out of the **65536** (ie. **2^16**) possible numbers from the 16 bits, half of them represent negative numbers and the remaining half represents positive numbers (including zero). Or in other words, **-32768 to 32767**.

If you don't need negative numbers, then you can change your variable type to `unsigned int` which  will use numbers up to a maximum of **65535**. So it becomes:

```
unsigned int count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But when I try while(count <= 40000), it does not stop counting.

"int" has a range from -32k to +32k-1. so "count <= 40000" will always be true as count is "int".